# Adding Service layer to Web APP to display DB contents on a jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

```
A Product class representing a real world entity of a product, it should be just a Javabean.

public class Product {
        private Long id; 
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private BigDecimal price;

        // Add/generate getters/setters/c'tors/equals/hashcode boilerplate.
    }
```

A ProductDAO:

```
public class ProductDAO {

    public List<Product> list() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

        try {
            connection = database.getConnection();
            statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id, name, description, price FROM product");
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
                product.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                product.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
                product.setPrice(resultSet.getBigDecimal("price"));
                products.add(product);
            }
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
        }

        return products;
    }

}
```

Servlet to obtain the list:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        List<Product> products = productDAO.list();
        request.setAttribute("products", products); // Will be available as ${products} in JSP
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain products from DB", e);
    }
}
```

And finally the jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
        <tr>
            <td>${product.name}</td>
            <td>${product.description}</td>
            <td>${product.price}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Guys i got this code from Stackoverflow itself.... Its similar to my project which i am working on... I just want to know if i wanna add Service Layer to this application what changes i must do... i tried putting list inside another method but it gave some errors... So some one please guide me on this.... There should be a method from servlet to service and then from service finally to DAO. Please guide me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new Service Class something like this:

```
public class ProductService {
    ProductDAO productDAO = new ProductDAO();

    public List<Product> list() throws SQLException{
       return productDAO.list();
    }
}
```

Add service instance in place of DAO instance to your servlet like this:

```
ProductService productService = new ProductService();
```

And then modify your doGet to use service instead of DAO:

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            List<Product> products = productService.list();
            request.setAttribute("products", products); // Will be available as ${products} in JSP
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain products from DB", e);
        }
}
```

This is a sample to get you started. You should move SQLException handling to service class instead of servlet.

Comment: Thank you soooo much for the answer..... I did it that way and it worked.... thank u for the guidance.....